# Can't get ShadowCopy to work

Tags: .net, vb.net, appdomain, shadow-copy

I have the following code in Assembly 1

```
Public Interface ITest
    Sub Run()
End Interface

Public Class Runner
    Inherits MarshalByRefObject

    Public Sub Run(pluginPath As String)
        For Each assemblyPath As String In Directory.GetFiles(pluginPath, "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            ScanAssemblyForTasks(assemblyPath)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub ScanAssemblyForTasks(assemblyPath As String)
        Dim assembly As Assembly = assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath)
        For Each type As Type In assembly.GetTypes().Where(Function(t) t.IsClass AndAlso
                                                                       Not t.IsAbstract AndAlso
                                                                       Not t.IsGenericType AndAlso
                                                                       GetType(ITest).IsAssignableFrom(t))

            Dim test As ITest = CType(type.GetConstructor(type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(Nothing), ITest)
            test.Run()
        Next
    End Sub
End Class

Module Module1

    Private mAppDomain As AppDomain
    Private mCachePath As String
    Private mPluginDirectory As String
    Private mRunner As Runner

    Sub Main()
        mCachePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase, "ShadowCache")
        mPluginDirectory = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase, "Assemblies")
        If (Not Directory.Exists(mCachePath)) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(mCachePath)
        End If
        If (Not Directory.Exists(mPluginDirectory)) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(mPluginDirectory)
        End If
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to load assemblies")
        Console.ReadKey()

        Dim setup As New AppDomainSetup()
        setup.ApplicationName = "MyApplication"
        setup.ShadowCopyFiles = "true"
        setup.CachePath = mCachePath
        setup.ShadowCopyDirectories = mPluginDirectory
        setup.ConfigurationFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile

        mAppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyApplication", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence, setup)

        mRunner = CType(mAppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(GetType(Runner).Assembly.FullName, GetType(Runner).FullName), Runner)
        mRunner.Run(mPluginDirectory)

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to end application")
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

End Module
```

And in Assembly2 that is located in `mPluginDirectory` i have the following code

```
Public Class Class1
    Implements ITest

    Public Sub Run() Implements ITest.Run
        Console.WriteLine("Run")
    End Sub
End Class
```

When i run the application Assembly2 is loaded into the application domain and "Run" is printed, but the directory `mCachePath` is empty and i can't modify/delete Assembly2.dll while the application is running, why dosen't .net use the shadow copy function when i told it to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, Replace `Assembly.LoadFile` with `Assembly.LoadFrom` and it just works don't ask me why...